# How to create nuget package with msbuild without rebuilding project?

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

I would like to setup a CI/CD pipeline with build, test and deploy stages.
I can build my project in build stage with

```
msbuild src\MyProject.csproj /t:Restore 
msbuild src\MyProject.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=../BuildOutput
```

Next I will build and run tests against `..\BuildOutput\MyProject.dll` that has already been built.

```
msbuild tests\MyProject.Tests.csproj /t:Restore
msbuild tests\MyProject.Tests.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=../BuildOutput /p:BuildProjectReferences=false
vstest.console BuildOutput\MyProject.Tests.dll
```

Up to this point it seems to work.

Now I would like to generate nuget package.
I can call:

```
msbuild src\MyProject.csproj /t:Pack /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=../BuildOutput /p:VersionPrefix=1.2.3
```

And that would create `MyProject.1.2.3.nupkg` in `BuildOutput` folder.
However it re-builds that project.

I'm looking something similar to `dotnet` cli.

```
dotnet pack --no-build
```

But I cannot use `dotnet` because my project has a COM reference.

I also looked into Nuget.exe, but it seems to throw an error when I call `nuget pack`

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type NuGet.Frameworks.NuGet.Frameworks1051960.NuGetFramework'.
```

**Does msbuild have a property that can skip build?**

Comment: It's newer but I'm partial to what was covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53568518/3543437

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on whether this is acceptable in your workflow, but you could use the `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>` property in a `<PropertyGroup>` of your `.csproj` file to get the package whenever you build your project. In case your tests do not go through, you can then discard the `.nupkg` file, but at least there is no additional rebuild for getting the NuGet package.

There is a more complete example of how to use this setting at the end of [the article *Easily supporting multiple target frameworks (TFMs) with VS2017 and Nuget*](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/iblogger/2017/04/05/easily-supporting-multiple-target-frameworks-tfms-with-vs2017-and-nuget/)<sup>1</sup>, but an exemplary very simple snippet would look like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: While the original link does not report a 404, it appears as blank in October 2021. The same article can, however, be found [on another URL](https://www.tamirdresher.com/blog/2017/04/05/Easily_supporting_multiple_target_frameworks_(TFMs)_with_VS2017_and_Nuget___IBlogger_-_Tamir_Dresher).

Comment: That flow crossed my mind as well. So in build stage I build my project and create that package. If it is time to deploy then I just ship the package that was generated in build stage. Although it feels a bit redundant to always create package in build stage, I still prefer usable pipeline over none at all :).

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to define this exclusively at build-time (e.g., as part of your CI configuration), instead of hard-coding it into your project file, you can instead use the `/t:build,pack` switch. This differs from just using `/t:pack` in that it will ensure any projects that aren't intended for packaging still get built, as would happen if there were a separate `/t:build` task.

Comment: @O.R. Mapper Can you tell me in which props or targets file the `GeneratePackageOnBuild` is defined ?

Comment: The link to "this article" is broken

Comment: @pvoosten: Thank you for pointing this out - I think I have found a second source for the article and added it to the answer.